# How to properly compute a buffer in meter around a lat / long location, with Shapely / Python

Tags: python, shapely

For this operation, we have two alternative implementations.

We notice very minor differences in the results for some particular lat / long. In addition I don't fully understand why point_buffer1, which does a single projection, can work, since we do the buffer operation prior to any projection. I understand why the second implem works (first projection to aeqd, buffer operation in meter, then project back in WGS84). But maybe it is overkill.

What is the best approach?

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

import pyproj
from pyproj import Transformer
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
standard_crs = "EPSG:4326"

def point_buffer1(lat: float, lon: float, radius: int):
    """
    Get the circle or square around a point with a given radius/length in meters.
    """

    # Azimuthal equidistant projection
    aeqd_proj = "+proj=aeqd +lat_0={lat} +lon_0={lon} +x_0=0 +y_0=0"

    transformer = Transformer.from_proj(aeqd_proj.format(lat=lat, lon=lon), standard_crs, always_xy=True)

    buffer = Point(0, 0).buffer(radius)

    return transform(transformer.transform, buffer)

def point_buffer2(lat: float, lon: float, radius: int):
    """
    Returns the geometry of a circle or square around a point with a given radius/length in meters.
    """

    point = Point(lon, lat)

    local_azimuthal_projection = f"+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={point.y} +lon_0={point.x}"

    wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"),
        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
    )

    aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
        pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"),
    )

    point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, point)

    buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius)

    buffer_wgs84 = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer)
    return buffer_wgs84
```

These two calls produce almost the same result, buffer around position 60, 0 (lat/long) with a 400 m radius

```
point_buffer1(60, 0, 400)
point_buffer2(60, 0, 400)
```

Slight difference with the radius of the result (around 1m or so). Any thoughts?

Comment: E.g for a lat / long of (60, 0) I am noticing this small difference in the radius. Not the same horizontally (2m or so) or vertically (1m or so).

So wondering if the 1st (single projection) or 2nd (two projections) implementation is the correct one, and why?

Comment: By checking the size of the bounding box of the produced geometry of each implementation, it seems that the 2nd implem with two projections is more precise than the first one.

The first one can have a discrepancy of the bounding box size of up to 0.5%, while the second is exact up to 0.01 %.

But still, I would be glad to have an explanation why we see this difference.

Answer (score 2):

1. While point_buffer1 and point_buffer2 use the same local_azimuthal_projection, the point_buffer2 uses an argument +R=6371000 which indicates that the representation of earth is a sphere of radius 6371 km. By default, if this argument is not indicated, the representation is ellipsoidal WGS84.

[image]

2. the distance calculation method used is haversine which assumes a spherical representation of earth. That's why the it is indeed more precise if we use a spherical representation of earth (with the +R=6371km argument). Choosing a different distance calculation method adapted to the ellispoid would yield more precise distance for case 1 than for case 2. That's why this domain is so hard !
3. The lat_0, lon_0 argument of the projection indicates the projection center already. https://proj.org/operations/projections/aeqd.html
   That's why it works with only one projection, because the 0,0 point in aeqd is projected to lat_0, lon_0 point in WGS84. Similarly, each point of the polygon buffered from the centroid are projected centered around lat_0, lon_0

To conclude, it appears that you get the best of both worlds if you use the projection of point_buffer2 inside point_buffer1